# Does PIX (Pico airport, Azores) have a luggage storage?

Tags: luggage-storage, azores

Does the Pico airport, close to Madalena in the Azores, have a left luggage facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick airport doesn’t have a luggage storage facility. To store your luggage you need to look for facilities near your end destination.